# Populate data through xml file for Android

Tags: android-widget

I am new to Android. I have created  a  navigation bar. After clicking to one of the buttons from the navigation bar a floating table should be displayed and data must be loaded through a xml file. Should I use listview or table layout for displaying the data? And also I need help with the code.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe show the small piece ofcode where you're stuck. In general we don't write code for you, but we're able to guide you to the next step.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the data comes from XML is irrelevant.

You probably want a table layout.

Your question is too broad for anyone to answer accurately.